# 80s cartoon fantasy movie with hero that has 3 heads

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I saw a cartoon movie as a child in the late 80s I barely remember.

In the movie there was a bad guy (a wizard maybe) and a team of heroes that traveled to defeat him. The movie had a fantasy (medieval?) theme. One of those heroes was a eagle human. When they fought against the bad guy the eagle human tried to attack and was thrown (cooked?) in a big cauldron.

The actual hero of the movie was a man that looked like three men triangularly stitched together. It appeared not before the end of the movie where he kicks some ass and the good guys win. I think the movie was named after the actual hero.

Comment: That three headed thing sounds like it would be inspired by eastern mythologies. In particular the hero Nezha, which could take that form. He didn't have any eagle companions though.

Comment: Another option would be some myth about Shiva and Garuda.

Comment: Other comments beg the question of where (geographically) and in what language you saw this?

Comment: Cerberus (3 dogs in 1)

Answer (score 2):

### *The Point*

The most probable candidate I suspect- though not a full match to something barely remembered.

It has a medieval theme. A character with 3 faces (most of the others are triangular). It aired in the 1980s.

*[The Point (1971)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Point!#Animated_television_film)*

[image]

[image]

[image]

### *The Son of the White Mare*

The 1981 Hungarian cartoon The Son of the White Mare has three brothers.

And this scene could be remembered as "triangularly stitched together" - though obviously most kids in 1981 wouldn't have seen this movie.

### *Gandahar*

[image]

I look forward to an actual answer with a triangular protagonist.

However I'll propose that perhaps some memories are being mashed up.  I hope the other users of this site will forgive an answer attempting to be helpful with multiple suggestions and pictures.

In addition to below suggestions other notable medieval fantasy may include "the Black Cauldron" or the non animated Krull or Dark Crystal.

The movie Gandahar (or Lightyears) has a multi-faced mutant. It also has some bird imagery.  The end of the movie is the hero jumping into a brain but there's enough things in the movie that could be remembered as a cauldron.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### *He-Man*

Alternatively episode of He-Man and the Masters of the Universe "Betrayal of Stratos" featuring his flying friend Stratos has eagle motifs and a demon in a cauldron. And since this was a series that raises the potential for more modified memories from multiple episodes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit: Additional speculation noting that Man-E-Faces in Masters of the Universe can switch between three faces. Again I realize this isn't a great match to the original question - but no alternatives have been proposed.

[image]

Comment: I think it would be better to make each possibility a separate answer. If the querent would accept this answer, what would that mean? Was it a _He-Man_ episode, was it _The Point_, was it _Gandahar_. or was it _The Son of the White Mare_?

Comment: @sqb well in this specific case we are dealing with very old vague memories where nothing was a super good match.  If there ever was a successful match the wrong parts can be edited out.

Comment: But now it's not clear your answer contains multiple answers. Even while typing my earlier comment, I almost overlooked _Gandahar_ being in there as well. Really, there's nothing wrong with multiple answers.

Comment: @SQB But why does it matter all that much *why* the OP chose to accept the answer? There are plenty of questions of here whose accepted answer includes more than 1 viable explanation, and the OP's are never required to explain what about the answer they found most convincing. If one of the proposed movies turns out to be the one they remember, good. That's their business.

Comment: @MishaR I'd like to know what they were actually remembering.  But in this particular case trying everything and seeing if anything sticks seemed acceptable. Obviously one to one correspondence between questions and answers is the ideal.

Comment: As it is, this answer is unclear. I would suggest posting an answer for each "answer" you have given here. We won't know which is the correct work with just an accept here, so how would future duplicates be closed, for example? And besides, multiple answers means more upvotes.